# Pass Progress Bar As Parameter?

Tags: c#

I have a method name DownloadProgressChanged. My program will be able to download multiple things, so therefore it will have different progressbars. The problem with DownloadProgressChanged is that I'm unsure how to get it to use a different progressbar depending on what is being downloaded. So essentially I'm wondering if I can pass the progressBar name through as a parameter when the method is called. (Like if downloading something else, progressBar2 will activate instead of progressBar1). My code is below.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressChanged);
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);


void DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    }
```

Comment: LOL! Downvoted within 30 seconds of posting the question. Typical StackOverflow.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465040/using-lambda-expressions-for-event-handlers. You can capture progress bar UI element inside the lambda

Comment: @pm100 May not be ideal if the OP doesn't want to use a lambda expression.

Comment: Yes always like that here with new members, @John Smith.

Comment: The lambda expression seems a bit more efficient, I'm just unsure how to implement it even after reading that link.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `Dictionary<WebClient, ProgressBar>`?

When creating your `WebClient`, assign the `WebClient` field of your dictionary to be the relevant `ProgressBar`.  You could then retrieve this `ProgressBar` in your `DownloadProgressChanged` method by casting `sender` to a `WebClient` and doing a lookup in your dictionary.