# How can I correctly pass an input parameter to an event handler method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am pretty new in **C#** and **.NET** and I have the following problem.

In my code I have something like this:

```
Table table = new Table();

lstLabelType.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(SelectDocumentTypeChanged);
```

that is attaching an event handler to a dropdown element into a view.

So when the user change the chosen value into this dropdown the **SelectDocumentTypeChanged()** method is performed, this one:

```
private void SelectDocumentTypeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("SelectDocumentTypeChanged() STARTED");

    SPWeb contextWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

    DropDownList listaTipiDocumenti = (DropDownList)sender;
    tipoDocumentoSelezionato = listaTipiDocumenti.SelectedValue;
    this.renderizzaEtichetteFacoltative(tipoDocumentoSelezionato, table);

    string url = contextWeb.Url;
    string link = url + "/ARXEIA WEBPART/Stampa Etichetta.aspx?IsDlg=1&postazione=" + macchina + "&tipoDoc=" + tipoDocumentoSelezionato;
    SPUtility.Redirect(link, SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context);


}
```

Now I have a problem. I have to pass to this event handler method the **Table table** object created in my code because into this method I have to use it.

How can I correctly implement this behavior? How can I pass this **Table table** object to the **SelectDocumentTypeChanged()** method when it is automatically called when the user change the value in my dropdown?

Comment: Is SelectDocumentTypeChanged and table are part of the same class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try writing your code like this:

```
Table table = new Table();

lstLabelType.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("SelectDocumentTypeChanged() STARTED");

    SPWeb contextWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

    DropDownList listaTipiDocumenti = (DropDownList)sender;
    tipoDocumentoSelezionato = listaTipiDocumenti.SelectedValue;
    this.renderizzaEtichetteFacoltative(tipoDocumentoSelezionato, table);

    string url = contextWeb.Url;
    string link = url + "/ARXEIA WEBPART/Stampa Etichetta.aspx?IsDlg=1&postazione=" + macchina + "&tipoDoc=" + tipoDocumentoSelezionato;
    SPUtility.Redirect(link, SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context);
};
```

Now you can simply use `table` directly in the event handler.

---

You can even ignore the `sender` now and do this:

```
lstLabelType.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("SelectDocumentTypeChanged() STARTED");

    SPWeb contextWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

    tipoDocumentoSelezionato = lstLabelType.SelectedValue;
    this.renderizzaEtichetteFacoltative(tipoDocumentoSelezionato, table);

    string url = contextWeb.Url;
    string link = url + "/ARXEIA WEBPART/Stampa Etichetta.aspx?IsDlg=1&postazione=" + macchina + "&tipoDoc=" + tipoDocumentoSelezionato;
    SPUtility.Redirect(link, SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context);
};
```

---

You can do this if you want to keep a separate method:

```
Table table = new Table();

lstLabelType.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, e) => SelectDocumentTypeChanged(lstLabelType, table);


private void SelectDocumentTypeChanged(DropDownList lstLabelType, Table table)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("SelectDocumentTypeChanged() STARTED");

    SPWeb contextWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

    tipoDocumentoSelezionato = lstLabelType.SelectedValue;
    this.renderizzaEtichetteFacoltative(tipoDocumentoSelezionato, table);

    string url = contextWeb.Url;
    string link = url + "/ARXEIA WEBPART/Stampa Etichetta.aspx?IsDlg=1&postazione=" + macchina + "&tipoDoc=" + tipoDocumentoSelezionato;
    SPUtility.Redirect(link, SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context);
}
```

Comment: I prefer to keep it as a separate method, is it possible?

Comment: @AndreaNobili - Why do you prefer to do that? It's poor encapsulation.

Comment: To keep this logic separate and have less code into my "main" class

Comment: @AndreaNobili - It really depends on your point-of-view. My method keeps the logic together with your event code making refactoring easier and it enables proper encapsulation.

Comment: Nice Solution. But be aware of a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2465054/9364460) that comes with it (even though i cant come up with a better solution)

Comment: @Hyarus - It's a super easy problem to solved. Just keep a reference to the handler to detach later or use `System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Create` (NuGet `System.Reactive`) to create an `IDisposable` that you can use to clean up the handler - you don't need to even keep a reference to the original handler then.