# Event from delegate vs lambda

Tags: c#, delegates

Is there any difference between creating C# event handler like this:

```
btnHey.Click += new EventHandler(delegate (object obj, EventArgs evn) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Hey"); });
```

and this:

```
btnHey.Click += (object obj, EventArgs evn) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Hey");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using lambda expressions for event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465040/using-lambda-expressions-for-event-handlers)

Comment: @HirasawaYui The question you refer to is about whether lambdas can be used for event handler (well, I know they can). I was interested to know whether there any differences between using a lambda and creating new delegate for an event. So Jon Skeet gives a very nice summary and clear answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, those are equivalent. There are actually six options to consider:

- `btnHey.Click += new EventHandler(delegate (object obj, EventArgs evn) { ... });`
- `btnHey.Click += new EventHandler(MethodName);`
- `btnHey.Click += delegate (object obj, EventArgs evn) { ... };`
- `btnHey.Click += MethodName;`
- `btnHey.Click += (object obj, EventArgs evn) => ...;` (Expression-bodied lambda)
- `btnHey.Click += (object obj, EventArgs evn) => { ... };` (Statement lambda)

... where `MethodName` is the name of a method with an appropriate signature. The parameters to the lambda expression can also be inferred, leading to even more options...

There *can* be some subtle differences between them in terms of whether or not a new delegate object is actually created. The options using method group conversions (`MethodName`) will *always* create a new object, at least at the time of writing. With the other options, the compiler *may* be able to cache a delegate object and reuse it - depending on whether it captures `this` or local variables. That's almost never significant, but worth knowing in the rare cases where you need micro-optimization.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the 4th (direct method name is short and intuitive as the old C style) and after (I like auto-typed lambdas), to the previous ones.

Comment: @OlivierRogier: Agreed. I've been trying to make it so the compiler can cache delegates created that way. First step is fixing the specification to allow it (I find it bizarre that `new` doesn't always mean new, but a method group conversion does). The ECMA C# 5 standard *does* allow for caching, and I'm trying to make sure that is maintained in later versions. Then we'll see whether the compiler team will actually use it :)

Comment: `btnHey.Click += (o, e) => {...}` seems to be an option as well

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: True - that's just "a lambda expression with implicitly typed parameters". Will note that.

Comment: While you're talking to the compiler team, could you please persuade them to allow a) open instance methods b) referring directly to a property getter or setter without reflection (the latter I use constantly to avoid dynamic functions)

Comment: @Charlieface: Those are *language* feature requests rather than *compiler* feature requests - I'd suggest filing issues in https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang

Comment: It will look better coming from you though https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1385 They should just allow the hidden `get_PropertyName` as a method group. Funny thing is that `get_PropertyName` already leaks via a CS0082 compiler error

Comment: @Charlieface: No, I'm not going to start adding my support for proposals because people ask me to. That would just open me up for a deluge of requests.